# how to properly call jquery functions

Tags: jquery, function

what is the best way of creating functions using jquery rather than just attaching functions to a button press.

at the moment I am calling regular javascript functions from jquery.

```
function generate_random(){}
$(click).click(function(){
     generate_random();
})
```

Comment: thanks for the replies! I am trying to improve upon my jquery and the assistance provided is great!

Answer (score 5):

There should be no need to wrap the call in an extra layer of function... so you can write;

```
function generate_random(){}
$(click).click(generate_random)
```

Function name are really just function pointers, which is also what is generated when you create an anonymous function like in `..click(function(){...})`

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfectly reasonable way to call a function in jQuery, assuming the first 'click' is actually an element selector. Alternatively, you can put whatever code is inside the generate_random() function into the place where you're currently calling generated_random() (i.e. inside the jQuery click function)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `generate_random` does not take any parameters (that would overwise conflict with parameters passed by jQuery event handler) you can rewrite that code simply as

```
function generate_random(){/* body */}
$(click).click(generate_random);
```

Alternatively if you are not calling `generate_random` anywhere else, then this would be more appropriate

```
$(click).click(function() {/* body */});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use .on()    (jQuery 1.7.x)

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    //functionality  generate_random
});
```

or

```
$(selector).on('click', generate_random);
```